# JAXB - are these objects stateless - JAXBContext, Marshaller, Unmarshaller

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

I am writing a library class in which I will have multiple methods which all need to start with this kind of code:

```
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(MODEL_PACKAGE);
    Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
    Unmarshaller um = jc.createUnmarshaller();
```

So I am thinking of reusing these 3 objects - the context, the marshaller, and the unmarshaller (i.e. I am thinking of constructing them once, and keeping them as object/instance fields/vars).

So... I wonder if they are 1) stateless and 2) thread-safe?

1) I mean, once I use e.g. the marshaller in one of my methods can I reuse it in another method without worrying that it can contain some leftover data from the previous time I used it?

2) Also are these objects thread-safe i.e. can I assume that my library class can be called from multiple threads without any risks, or not (if I store these objects as object variables)?

Comment: @user158037 My question is not a duplicate of this one. I am also asking about stateless/stateful. And I am not asking only about marshaller's thread-safety. So the question you refer to has a much more limited scope. Next time you may want to think more before marking duplicates. Lately almost anything I try to ask here is almost immediately being tried to be  categorized as a duplicate.

Comment: If something is not thread-safe, then it usually is statefull (otherwise, thread safety usually is not an issue).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel That's a good point. Yes... OK.

Answer (score 2):

JAXBContext - is thread safe and can (and must) be a singleton. Creation is expensive operation.

Marshaller and Unmarshaller **are not thread safe!**. You must create them every time. Creation is not expensive and takes almost no time (less than 1 millisecond).

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure about this? Can you give me some authoritative reference? What about stateless/stateful?

Comment: `JAXBContext` must not necessarily be a singleton.

Comment: @lexicore - Not necessary, but huge performance impact when used in any service implementation it it is not. Choice is yours...

Comment: @peter.petrov - I work with JAXB for about 10 years. There is no such thing as staless/statefull for JAXB :-), so it is stateless. Proper implementation is - create JAXBContext once, but marshallers/unmarshallers each time and only inside the method, do not keep them anywhere outside, like instance or static variables because they are not thread safe. It is also better to have number of JAXBContexts, not just big one which has all known Namespaces in it. There is old and existing problem - Marshaller puts all known by Context namespaces into XML regardless of where they using.

Comment: If there were "no such thing as staless/statefull for JAXB", marshaller/unmarshaller would thread safe. But they are not.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I got it.

Comment: @lexicore staless/statefull is a different conception from thread safety. But it is another discussion I would not go into ... :-)

Comment: If something is not thread-safe, it is usually because it is statefull (without appropriate synchronization), so there is a relation between the two.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - yes. But not necessary vice-versa.

Comment: @Vadim The point is, "There is no such thing as staless/statefull for JAXB :-), so it is stateless." is false. Take a look at the source code of `MarshallerImpl` and `UnmarshallerImpl`, they pretty well have state. And this is the reason for them to be non-thread-safe.